# linear combination of $w = (\sin x + \cos x)^2$ with three given vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Show that the vector $w$ is a linear combination of $v_{1}$,$v_{2}$ and $v_{3}$ where:
> $$w = (\sin x + \cos x)^2, v_{1} = e^x+1, v_{2} = e^x-1, v_{3}=\sin2x$$ for vector space $C(\mathbb{R})$.

How do I calculate calculate the linear combination for a trigonometric function?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Actually, it's right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here,
w= (sin X+ cosX)^2 = (sinX)^2+ (cosX)^2 + 2sinXcosX

= 1 + 2sinX•cosX

= 1+ sin 2X

= 1/2 (e^x+ 1) - 1/2 (e^x-1) + sin2X

Hence, w=1/2•V1 - 1/2•V2 + V3

Hence, w can be expressed as linear combination of given vectors.